# Is it possible to refer foreign key with both classes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Suppose I have two classes `Country` and `Currency`, and I want to create a relation between them using EF.

```
public class Country
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;} 

    public long? CurrencyId {get; set;}
    public Currency Currency {get; set;}
}

public class Currency
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;} 

    public long? CountryId {get; set;}
    public Country Country {get; set;}
}
```

I can't manage this, I have some models in the same type. Like `User` and `Organization`.

An `Organization` has `Nullable UserId`, and `User` has a `Nullable organization`. How can I manage this?

Comment: Those business cases are not a good fit for needing to create a circular dependency between these types. Both of those sound like a one to many or a many to many. A country has 1 currency and a currency has one or more countries (one to many). A user belongs to many organizations and an organization has many users (many-to-many). When modeling this you would have an reference to an entity on one side and a collection on the other. With a many to many it would be a collection on both sides.

Comment: Again, I do not see a business need to have FKs on both ends and would not recommend doing that unless you have a clear business need to do so.

Comment: I agree with Igor, this seems a many-to-many. How would you map the currency 'euro' for example, it is used in multiple countries so your model can't handle that.

Comment: Actually Organization class has CreatedById and User has nullable organizational, that's the problem, I know Its Looks like One to many, means User can have Multiple Organizations.

Comment: Is an organisation unique to the user who created it? No other users can ‘join’ it (guessing about what organisation means now ofc in your domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely have these kinds of relationships, but they have to be configured correctly, and sometimes you have to insert entities and later update them to work around the enforcement of FKs at insert-time rather than commit-time.

In particular EF has no convention to match up the inverse navigation properties when there are multiple relationships between two entities.

EG

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(EfCore3Test.Department.Members))]
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(EfCore3Test.Department.Manager))]
    public virtual ICollection<Department> ManagedDepartments { get; } = new HashSet<Department>();
}
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; } = new HashSet<Person>();
    public Person Manager { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
}
```

And you typically can't have cascading behavior on all the FKs, so you configure at least one to not cascade.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(d => d.Members)
            .WithOne(m => m.Department)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Country
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;} 

    public long? CurrencyId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("CurrencyId")]
    public virtual Currency Currency {get; set;}
}

public class Currency
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;} 

    public long? CountryId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country {get; set;}
}
```

you will need to reference `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`